# How to implement this additional condition in my UPDATE statement in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I am running SQL Server 2014 and I need to update a table (`NameInfo`) based on the values in the column of another table (`NamesCleaned`).

Let us assume this is the `[NameInfo]` table:

```
    ID       FirstName       LastName      PrimaryGuest
    -----------------------------------------------------
    100        J              Hopkins           +
    100        S              Hopkins           -
    150        A              Donohue           +
    170        Peter          Smith             +
    170        Sarah          Smith             -
```

And here is the `[NamesCleaned]` table:

```
    ID       FirstName          LastName
    --------------------------------------
    100       James             Hopkins
    150       Allan             Donohue
```

I need to replace the `FirstName` of all records in `[NameInfo]` table using the values in the `[NamesCleaned]` table.

So, my expected output should look like this:

```
    ID       FirstName       LastName      PrimaryGuest
    ---------------------------------------------------
    100        James          Hopkins           +
    100        S              Hopkins           -
    150        Allan          Donohue           +
    170        Peter          Smith             +
    170        Sarah          Smith             -
```

Updates will need to be done only for records where `[PrimaryGuest] = '+'` and all records in the `[NamesCleaned]` table refer to those guests with a '+' sign.

Now, here is how my T-SQL query stands:

```
UPDATE [NameInfo]
SET [NameInfo].[FirstName] = b.[FirstName]
FROM [NameInfo] a
INNER JOIN [NamesCleaned] b ON a.[ID] = b.[ID];
```

My problem:

How to plug-in the Primary Guest = '+' into my above query? I guess if I leave this condition out, the query will also update records where PrimaryGuest = '-'

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: use a WHERE clause.

Comment: Do I add this at the end of my query?

Comment: yeah, same as if it were just a normal SELECT query. You can actually change your UPDATE to say "UPDATE a" and it knows that's the alias of NameInfo. I almost always write my UPDATEs as a SELECT first to make sure it all looks right.

Comment: Thanks. Please post as an answer and I'll vote accordingly.

Comment: It's quite clearly shown [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: yeah, it's not really "answer" worthy. Glad it worked for you though.